# What is an appropriate background for cognitive modeling?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, reference-request, cognitive-modeling

Awhile back, I picked up *Cognitive Modeling* by Thad A. Polk (published in 2002 by MIT Press - and yes, before anyone points it out, I do realize that that's probably somewhat out of date at this point given its age). I found that I was somewhat confused by it, though. What is the appropriate background for this topic?

I'd give a little more of my personal background for context, but I'm not looking for personalized advice so much as a general explanation of what kinds of things (beyond an "ordinary" introduction to cognitive psychology) would be helpful to understanding this topic.

Comment: Could you include some examples of things you were confused by? Probably more meaningful than the paragraph on 'personal background' and 'Google' (I suggest you drop these).

Comment: @StevenJeuris Sure - I have a few appointments this morning but will try to do so this afternoon.